# EF Core migrations not working in in ASP.NET Core web project. Empty Up/Down

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I just started building a new ASP.Net Core website using EF Core. I created the template using the normal template in Visual Studio with User Authenticaion. Very basic. ApplicationDbContext and migrations is included and I successfully updated the database with the identity tables.
I then add my own classes and add them to the ApplicationDbContext as DbSet. Tried with Add-Migration but the Up and Down methods are empty.. I have tried different solutions but most of them suggest to add dbset to the db context class... Which I have already done.
What am I not seeing here?

ApplicationDbContext

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserManual> UserManuals { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<UserManualCustomer>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.CustomerId, t.UserManualId});

        builder.Entity<UserManualCustomer>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Customer)
            .WithMany(p => p.UserManualCustomer)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CustomerId);

        builder.Entity<UserManualCustomer>()
                        .HasOne(pt => pt.UserManual)
                        .WithMany(p => p.UserManualCustomer)
                        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserManualId);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public const string ConnectionString = @"Server=Server=(localdb)\\ProjectsV13;Database=FSCIDb;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved the problem... Sort of. As an insanity check I created a new web project and added one file at a time. Worked! I think I messed up the other web project by moving around the ApplicationDbContext classe and the Data folder with the Migrations... So I will just leave it be :)